# listing rows with the most recent date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that lists contract dates.  A contract can have multiple dates, so I only want the most recent one.

I tried ranking by the contractEnded date, and then filtering so that I only get the 1st ranking, but I keep getting a syntax error:

***Invalid column name 'contractRank'.***

```
SELECT MAX(contractEnded) AS contractEnded, contractID, contractStarted, contractEnded, userID, examID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  partition by userID
                  ORDER BY MAX(contractEnded) desc)
                  AS contractRank
FROM examcontract es
WHERE examID = 92855231134
and es.contractRank = 1
GROUP BY  userID, examID, contractID, contractStarted, contractEnded
```

Is there a way to do this in mssql 2012?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use an alias from the select clause in `WHERE`, `ON`, `GROUP BY`, etc. Use a CTE. `WITH x AS (SELECT MAX ...) SELECT * FROM x WHERE contractRank = 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ranking functions are not available to manipulate in the query they are used, you will need to use an outer query to manipulate any ranking function.

Also you do not need to use MAX() function to get the last date when using Ranking function, The below query will return Last Contract end date for each userID in your table.

```
SELECT contractEnded, contractID, contractStarted, contractEnded, userID, examID
FROM (
     SELECT contractEnded, contractID, contractStarted, contractEnded, userID, examID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by userID ORDER BY contractEnded desc)  AS contractRank
     FROM examcontract 
    WHERE examID = 92855231134
     )A
WHERE  A.contractRank = 1
```

As Aaron Mentioned in your comments section, you can also use CTE (Common Table Expression) to achieve the same results.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
 (
  SELECT contractEnded, contractID, contractStarted, contractEnded, userID, examID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by userID ORDER BY contractEnded desc)  AS contractRank
  FROM examcontract es
  WHERE examID = 92855231134
 )
SELECT contractEnded, contractID, contractStarted, contractEnded, userID, examID
FROM CTE 
WHERE contractRank = 1
```